# Are all sets inevitably topological spaces?

Tags: general-topology

In ZFC on every set $A$ a total order relation can be defined such that there is a least element. As far as I can see, this order relation can be used to define the order topology in $A$ and thus make $A$ a topological space. That is, *any* set can be given a topological space structure via this procedure. Am I right or am I forgetting some subtle point?

Comment: Yes, this is correct, though you do need the C in ZFC. Of course you can also make any set into a discrete topological space, or give it the cofinite topology, or ...

Comment: Any set $A$ can be endowed with the discrete topology defined by the Power set $\mathcal{P}(A)$

Comment: Also, for any set, you could define a linear order that generates the discrete topology. For finite sets this should be clear. If the set is infinite, then first well-order it, then insert a decreasing sequence in front of each limit ordinal, and then consider the order topology. (This procedure does not increase the cardinality of the infinite set.) (Also, everyone points out the discrete topology, it makes me feel the indiscrete topology is neglected, then the only open sets are the empty set and the set $A$ :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are quite correct. The Ordering Principle states that every set can be ordered (which can be proved using the Axiom of Choice's equivalent: the Well-Ordering Theorem). Once a set is endowed with an order, one can then endow it with the order topology that corresponds.

As the comments point out, though, this need not be the *only* way to topologize a set $A$. In particular, if $A$ has more than one element, then the indiscrete topology $\{\emptyset,A\}$ is distinct from any order topology one might give $A,$ as it is not Hausforff (while order topologies necessarily are). There are also numerous other topologies that one might use, like the discrete topology, the cofinite topology, topologizing $A$ as a disjoint union of indiscrete spaces on the members of some partition of $A,$ and many more. Depending on how many elements $A$ has, some (or all, or none) of these need coincide. In the case that $A$ has at most one element, all topologies coincide.